# Display media images from directly Digitalocean app platform

Tags: django, image, digital-ocean

I hosted web app to digital ocean app platform, but media files aren't displaying at all, is there any way to serve that from digital ocean and not to use aws.

models file:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']
```

view file:

```
class ProjectList(generic.ListView):
model = models.Projects
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.ProjectList.as_view(), name='all'),
path('postmodernism/', include('postmodernism.urls', namespace='postmodernism')),
path('newstories/', include('newstories.urls', namespace='newstories')),

]
```

template:

```
  {% extends 'projects/projects_base.html' %}

{% block projects_content %}
    {% for projects in projects_list %}
        {% include 'projects/_projects.html' %}
        {% if projects.title == 'პოსტ მოდერნიზმი' %}
            <a href="{% url 'projects:postmodernism:postindex' %}"><img src="{{ projects.image.url }}" alt="postmodernism" width="100" height="100"></a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if projects.title == 'ამბების ახლებური განვითარება' %}
            <a href="{% url 'projects:newstories:all' %}"><img src="{{ projects.image.url }}" alt="newstories" width="100" height="100"></a>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your question directly: there is no feasible way of serving media files "directly" from Django App on DO App Platform.

The App Platform uses "ephemeral file system", just like Heroku. And whereas it is possible to cram your static files as part of the application's slug, the media files need to be served from outside location (such as DigitalOcean Spaces).